# AspnetCore Multiple authentication and use of AddAuthorization/AddAuthentication/UseAuthentication

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, authorization

I'm try to learn ASPNetCore 2.2
I don't understand how authentication chains works.

Example: Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
                services.AddMvcCore()
                        .AddAuthorization();                // Note 1

                services.AddAuthentication(options => {     // Note 2
                      options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;
                      options.DefaultChallengeScheme    = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme;})
                .AddJwtBearer(x => {
                              x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                              x.SaveToken            = true;                                      
                              x.TokenValidationParameters = tvp;})
                .AddApiKeySupport(options => { });
    }



    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        app.UseStatusCodePages()
           .UseResponseCompression()
           //.UseAuthentication()                            // NOTE 3
           .UseMvc();
    }
```

**ApiKeyHandler.cs**

```
public class ApiKeyHandler  : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync() {
        log.Debug("Checking API key");

        // No API KeyProvided. Pass to next auth handler (JWT)
        if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue(ApiKeyHeaderName, out var apiKeyHeaderValues)) {
            return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
        }

        if (checkAuthHeader(foo)) {
            ticket = createTicket(foo);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
}
```

**TestController.cs**

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
public class TestApiController : Controller {

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme)]
    [HttpGet("api-jwt")]
    public IActionResult APIAndJWT() {
        var message = $"API and JWT !!! {nameof(APIAndJWT)}";
        return new ObjectResult(message);
    }



    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("only-jwt")]
    public IActionResult OnlyJWT() {
        var message = $"JWT {nameof(OnlyJWT)}";

        return new ObjectResult(message);
    }



    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme)]
    [HttpGet("only-api")]
    public IActionResult OnlyAPI() {
        var message = $"            API       {nameof(OnlyAPI)}";

        return new ObjectResult(message);
    }
 }
```

Ok, TestApi is very simple. I want to call some endpoint using JWT auth or an API Key. Other endpoints can be called with both auth.
There are three methods. One use only JWT auth, one only API auth, and another that can use JWT or API auth.
I don't know how works those methods:

- AddAuthorization()      // Note 1
- AddAuthentication(...)  // Note 2
- UseAuthentication()     // Note 3

Well, **without AddAuthorization()** it seems that my [Authorize] attribute wont used, so I have free access to all API. **BAD**. On MSDN AddAuthorization() seems to enable policy that I don't use.
I **must** use AddAuthorization() for managing simple access to API?

**AddAuthentication()** it's easy. It just configure my auth handlers (JWT and a custom API handler)

**UseAuthentication** here is the problem. I think that enables the middlewares added with AddAuthentication(...) // Note 2

My question: it's correct that each route create a new instance of ApiKeyHandler?
For example in route **/only-jwt** I specify only JWT authschema, but ApiKeyHandler is always created/called.

**REMOVING** UseAuthentication() instead do same results, ie authenticated routes, but without creating useless ApiKeyHandler when not required (**/only-jwt**).
What's the correcy way?

I think that the order AddMvc() / AddAuthorization() - AddMvc / UseAuthentication() is correct.

Comment: Does it work for you? Have you got it working with Net Core 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by me.

1. AddAuthorization() is needed when you use UseMvcCore() because isn't automatically like UseMVC()
2. There was a bug in AspNetCore 2.2
3. UseAuthentication() use the standard auth pipeline so each AuthMiddleware is created and chained with others.